# Solve gives an incorrect answer

Tags: numerics, evaluation

```
Cond11[B_, A_, En_] := 4 + 2 Sqrt[1 + 4 B] - A^2/(2 (-En)^(3/2))

Cond22[B_, A_, En_] := 2 - (A^2 (3 + 2 Sqrt[1 + 4 B]))/(2 (-En)^(3/2))

Solve[{Cond11[B, A, En] == 0, Cond22[B, A, En] == 0}, {B, En}]
```

Putting the result back into `Cond11` or `Cond22` does not yield zero.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 5):

From the documentation:

- [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) uses non-equivalent transformations to find solutions of transcendental equations and hence it may not find some solutions and may not establish exact conditions on the validity of the solutions found.
- With `Method->Reduce`, [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) uses only equivalent transformations and finds all solutions.

So, the non-equivalent transformations used by [`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve) are introducing spurious solutions. To avoid this:

```
Solve[{Cond11[B, A, En] == 0, Cond22[B, A, En] == 0}, {B, En}, Method->Reduce]
```

> {}

showing that your equations have no solutions.

Comment: How about the result of NSolve in my answer?

Comment: @ user64494 `NSolve` is basically just invoking `Solve` in this case.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau: If you execute the codes of OP and me, you will see quite different results. Can you base your claim?

Comment: @user64494 I checked by tracking it in a debugging kernel. The difference in results is probably due to an intermediate result factoring in the exact case, at the `Roots` step.

Answer (score 0):

Making use of `NSolve` instead of `Solve`, one obtains

```
Cond11[B_, A_, En_] := 4 + 2 Sqrt[1 + 4 B] - A^2/(2 (-En)^(3/2));
Cond22[B_, A_, En_] := 2 - (A^2 (3 + 2 Sqrt[1 + 4 B]))/(2 (-En)^(3/2));
NSolve[{Cond11[B, A, En] == 0, Cond22[B, A, En] == 0}, {B, En}]
```

> {{B -> 0.875 - (
>       0.21875 A^2 Sqrt[-1. Root[1. A^8 + 20. A^4 #1^3 + 64. #1^6 &, 
>          1]])/Root[1. A^8 + 20. A^4 #1^3 + 64. #1^6 &, 1]^2, 
>     En -> Root[1. A^8 + 20. A^4 #1^3 + 64. #1^6 &, 1]}, {B -> 
>      0.875 - (
>       0.21875 A^2 Sqrt[-1. Root[1. A^8 + 20. A^4 #1^3 + 64. #1^6 &, 
>          2]])/Root[1. A^8 + 20. A^4 #1^3 + 64. #1^6 &, 2]^2, 
>     En -> Root[1. A^8 + 20. A^4 #1^3 + 64. #1^6 &, 2]}, {B -> 
>      0.875 - (
>       0.21875 A^2 Sqrt[-1. Root[1. A^8 + 20. A^4 #1^3 + 64. #1^6 &, 
>          3]])/Root[1. A^8 + 20. A^4 #1^3 + 64. #1^6 &, 3]^2, 
>     En -> Root[1. A^8 + 20. A^4 #1^3 + 64. #1^6 &, 3]}, {B -> 
>      0.875 - (
>       0.21875 A^2 Sqrt[-1. Root[1. A^8 + 20. A^4 #1^3 + 64. #1^6 &, 
>          4]])/Root[1. A^8 + 20. A^4 #1^3 + 64. #1^6 &, 4]^2, 
>     En -> Root[1. A^8 + 20. A^4 #1^3 + 64. #1^6 &, 4]}, {B -> 
>      0.875 - (
>       0.21875 A^2 Sqrt[-1. Root[1. A^8 + 20. A^4 #1^3 + 64. #1^6 &, 
>          5]])/Root[1. A^8 + 20. A^4 #1^3 + 64. #1^6 &, 5]^2, 
>     En -> Root[1. A^8 + 20. A^4 #1^3 + 64. #1^6 &, 5]}, {B -> 
>      0.875 - (
>       0.21875 A^2 Sqrt[-1. Root[1. A^8 + 20. A^4 #1^3 + 64. #1^6 &, 
>          6]])/Root[1. A^8 + 20. A^4 #1^3 + 64. #1^6 &, 6]^2, 
>     En -> Root[1. A^8 + 20. A^4 #1^3 + 64. #1^6 &, 6]}}

Addition. Also

```
FindRoot[{Cond11[B, A, En] == 0, Cond22[B, A, En] == 0} /. A -> 1, {{B, 1}, {En, 1}}]
```

> {B -> -1.10628 - 1.69546*10^-15 I, En -> 0.944732 + 0.168628 I}

Comment: It doesn't appear that the result of NSolve or FindRoot is close to a zero of the conditions, for any value of `A`.  (Plug into the functions.)

Comment: @Michael E2: I did try the verification for some values of A. Indeed, the result was wrong or unclear to me. So we deal with a serious bug in NSolve/FindRoot.

Comment: `FindRoot` gives an error/warning, so I wouldn't call that a bug.  But I expect more from `NSolve`, which gives no error; I agree that's a bug.

Comment: @Michael E2: Did your verify FindRoot for all complex values of A?

Comment: Obviously not for **all** values of A, just a few thousand, like this `{Cond11[B, A, En], Cond22[B, A, En]} /. A -> # /. FindRoot[{Cond11[B, A, En] == 0, Cond22[B, A, En] == 0} /. A -> #, {{B, 1 + 0. I}, {En, 1}}] & /@ RandomComplex[1/10 {-5 - 5 I, 5 + 5 I}, 1000] // Chop[#, 1*^-3] & // Unitize // Flatten // DeleteDuplicates // Quiet`, with different domains for `RandomComplex`. It seems to me that the result of `Reduce[{Cond11[B, A, En] == 0, Cond22[B, A, En] == 0}]` indicates one should consider why there is no solution.